# SVN Mac - Stripping files of SVN meta data?

Tags: svn, macos, version-control

I downloaded some source files on a Mac that were previously part of some working copy on the authors computer, I need to use these files in another repository but the SVN client "Versions" for Mac is picking up on the data from this old repository. I can't find the ".SVN" folder anywhere... any idea on how to "cleanse" these files so I can commit them to my repository?

Comment: the directories are .svn in lowercase which are hidden by default in Finder, and ls in terminal without doing ls -la

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The .svn folder is just a hidden directory which will appear in every (or at least most) of the directories in your source tree.

To remove all of them, you can open up Terminal, navigate to your source directory, and then use the following line (found [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2486)):

```
find . -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: As usual, please be careful when messing about in the Terminal :)

Answer (score 1):

The `.svn` folder can sometimes be named `_svn`. You can try looking for those folders and removing them.

Also, if your Subversion client (Versions) sees the folder as a working copy, you can try to perform SVN export from the folder to itself. It should clean the SVN meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

As an indirect answer, I would highly recommend the Finder replacement shell [PathFinder](http://cocoatech.com/) to any developers on Macs.  It's useful for many reasons, the relevant one to this post being the ability to show hidden files/folders by default (which I always keep on).  I've done this exact thing before -- simply find all ".svn" folders in your root folder using PathFinder and nuke them -- much safer than mass deleting in terminal (at least for some of us :)

[No, I have no relation to the company, I'm merely a happy customer.]

Answer (score 0):

Remove Subversion .svn Folders on Mac OS X

If you need to clean up a folder on Max OS X that was previously under Subversion, you need to remove the hidden `.svn/` folders.

Here is a quick terminal command that can do the job:

Open Terminal (Applications -> Utilities)

cd to the folder you want to clean up

Run

```
find ./ -name ".svn" | xargs rm -Rf
```

You are now free of Subversion's source control.